# Quota on outstanding pull requests

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

Earlier today I noticed the following error in my logs:

```
503 Too many outstanding pull requests for subscription '<...>'.
Please reduce the number of simultaneous Pull() requests invoked for
this subscription. (POST https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<...>:pull)
```

I tried searching for the exact quantity of allowed simultaneous pull requests, but can't seem to find it anywhere. The only mention of this error I find is [here in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull), but again, no numbers are stated.

I have 40 processes pulling from the subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens when there is a transient overload on a specific instance of a Cloud Pub/Sub server to which some of your requests are being routed. The error message is admittedly poor and should not tell you to reduce your pull requests and I will remedy that.